# Implementing insertion sort, passing list to other class?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, insertion

i posted a version of the code yesterday but i thought it could handle some improvement or something. the thing is im stuck again. as you can see im trying to sort a linked list and write it back to the text file. the first question would be, what and how to pass in the Insertion class? and the second question is how to implement Insertion sort ALPHABETICALLY? i've seen numerous examples of insertion with integers and arrays but i still seem to be having trouble. Here is my progress so far.

EDIT 1: forget about that.

EDIT 2: how to implement Comparable and use alphabetical sort (CompareToIgnoreCase) with my method?

Main:

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class Sort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        File outputFile ;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in) ; 
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList() ;
        String command ;
        Insertion insertion = new Insertion() ;

        // Create the new text file. If exists, it will continue to the next commands
        do
        {
            outputFile = new File("db.txt") ;

                if(!outputFile.exists())
                {
                    outputFile.createNewFile ();                    
                    System.out.println("The file was created as db.txt");
                    System.out.println("");
                }

        }while (!outputFile.exists()) ;

        // Define which file to stream in from          
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("db.txt") ;
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (fileIn) ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (input)) ;
        String line ;

        try
        {               
            // Read each line of the file               
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                list.add(line) ;
            }       
            input.close() ;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error. Could not read the file") ;
        }

        //System.out.println (list.toString()) ;

        //Welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome. \nPlease use the following commands [-i for Insertion Sort, -s for Selection Sort, -m for Merge sort, Exit to terminate]: " );
        System. out.println ("") ;          
        command = kb.next() ;

        do
        {
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("-i"))
            {
                insertion.Sort(list, list.size()) ;

                //try
                //{
                    //the "true" argument sets the FileWriter to append mode so that is does not overwrite the first line
                //  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("db.txt", true));
                    //out.write(textContent) ;
                    //out.newLine() ;
                    //out.close() ;
                //}catch(IOException e)
                //{
                //  System.out.println("Could not write to file") ;
                //  System.exit(0) ;
                //}

                //System.out.println ("Enter command:") ;
                //command = kb.next() ;

            }

            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("-s"))
            {

            }
            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("-m"))
            {

            }
            else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
            {
                System.exit(0) ;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Unknown command. Please use -i, -s, -m or EXIT") ;
                command = kb.next() ;
            }
        }while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) ;

    }
}
```

LinkedList:

```
    import java.lang.* ;

public class LinkedList
{
    //reference to the head node
    public Node head ;
    public int listCount ;

    //LinkedList Constructor
    public LinkedList ()
    {
        //empty list
        head = new Node (null) ;
        listCount = 0 ;
    }

    //add element to the end of the list
    public void add(String data)
    {
        Node temp = new Node (data) ;
        Node current = head ;

        //go to the end of the list
        while (current.getNext() != null)
        {
            current = current.getNext() ;
        }

        // last node\s next reference is set to the last node
        current.setNext(temp) ;
        //increment the number of elements
        listCount++ ; 
    }

    //return the size of the list
    public int size()
    {
        return listCount ;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        Node current = head.getNext() ;
        String output = " " ;
        while (current != null)
        {
            output += "[" + current.getData().toString() + "]" ;
            current = current.getNext() ;
        }
        return output ;
    }


}
```

Insertion:

```
public class Insertion 
{
    public static void Sort (LinkedList listIn, int size)
    {
        int temp, i, j ;
        for (j=1;j<size;j++)
        {
            while(listIn.head)
        }
    }
}
```

The Node Class:

```
    public class Node 
    {
        //reference to the next node or null if not any
        Node next ;
        //the entries
        String data ;

        //Node Constructor
        public Node (String dataIn)
        {
            next = null ;
            data = dataIn ;
        }

        //Node constructor in case of the need to point to a certain node
        public Node (String dataIn, Node nextIn)
        {
            next = nextIn;
            data = dataIn ;
        }

        public String getData ()
        {
            return data ;
        }

        public void setData (String dataIn)
        {
            data = dataIn ;
        }

        public Node getNext ()
        {
            return next ;
        }

        public void setNext (Node nextIn)
        {
            next = nextIn ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what and how to pass in the Insertion class?

You mean method? You should pass in (at least) the full `LinkedList` (rather than just the head `Node`).

> and the second question is how to implement Insertion sort ALPHABETICALLY?

Either you take in lists of elements whose type implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or take a separate [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) parameter, and use that to compare the elements. Then you can pass in a `StringComparator` for a list of `String`s, an `IntComparator` for `Integer`s etc. All you need is to implement the needed Comparator, which is usually trivial, and you can thus reuse your sort algorithm for any type you wish.

The first approach is simpler, and it works for `String`s straight out of the box (as `String` already implements `Comparable`). Note however, that it is limited to object types - for primitive types such as `int`, you need the second approach. Then again, you can't have generic collections storing elements of primitive types.

You can see an example to the two kinds of generic `sort` method in [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

If you want to keep your `LinkedList` nongeneric though, you can remove (most of) the generic fluff:

```
public static void sort(LinkedList list);
public static void sort(LinkedList list, Comparator<? super String> c)
```

Comment: is there any way that i dont have to use ready-made java classes? this is not homework by any means, its just my way of learning java better.

Comment: @voth1234, you don't have to - `Comparator` is an interface which you can implement yourself any way you want. The `sort` methods are just shown as an example to the proper method signature - feel free to implement your own, however it is good to learn from the start the best practices and conventions regarding APIs etc. Moreover, after you did your own implementation, it may even be insightful to look at the implementation of the `Collections.sort` methods and see what they do differently, then figure out why.

Comment: i will work on that thanks. Take a look at my Sort method above. i passed the list and printed it (so that probably that means that it passed through correctly) but it wont stop printing, it's stuck in an infinite loop. i fail to see the problem though. any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any obvious bugs. Try adding a method which iterates through the list the same way as `toString`, but instead of appending the node data to a local `String`, it prints it out directly to the screen. Then compare the output of that method with the expected contents of the list - that may give you a clue.

Comment: Question. What exactly from the above code needs to implement comparable? Also i tried to print directly as you said but i failed :). is there any way i can write the passed list that is in the sort method, to the text file?

Comment: @voth1234, in your specific case, `String`, which in fact already implements it. What do you mean by "failed"?

Comment: and how to use it the CompareToIgnoreCase in my method. BTW, take a look at my edited code. i created a new class just for the Node. Also see what i pass in the method, and what i do in the method (a loop basically). this is the error i get: "type mismatch. cannot convert from LinkedList.Node to Node. Dont worry about the print thing for now.

Comment: @voth1234, for case-insensitive comparison, you need to implement your own `Comparator`. The type mismatch sounds like you need to recompile all your code to update all classes which used to depend on `LinkedList.Node`.

Comment: The thing is that this error was there before i split the Node to another class. That was the main reason i did that actually, to see if it needed to be created in its own class

Comment: @voth1234, you may be importing another `Node` class from a different package?